# FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized Is False

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the Facebook C# 5.3.2 JavaSDK.  I am reviewing the sample code for CS-AspNetWebForms-JsSdk.  The **IsAuthorized** properly is not behaving correctly.

I authenticated to facebook.com.  Next, I start the sample ASP Web Form app.  It defaults to the apps login page (i.e., the Login To Facebook is displaying).  I simply press F5 to refresh the page.  This time, the **IsAuthorized** property is set to True (which it should have done the first time).

**Q:** Why is **IsAuthorized** false the first time the page is loaded?  After the refresh, it's value is set properly.

Environment:
* IE 9
* Facebook C# 5.3.2 SDK

Thanks in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

This is working correctly for me:

```cs
var fbWebContext = FacebookWebContext.Current;
if (fbWebContext != null && fbWebContext.IsAuthorized())
{
    var facebook = new FacebookWebClient(fbWebContext);
    JsonObject user = (JsonObject)facebook.Get("me");
    Session["FBid"] = (string)user["id"];
    // User has open facebook session. Do something.
}
else
{
    // User has no facebook session or has not authorized the app. Do something.
}
```

Tried on ie9. Could you post your code please to have a look a it.